# Bounds on the questions/answers ratio

Tags: discussion, questions

I originally arrived here from the mathematics stackexchange website. I'm also interested in TeX, but I am by no means an expert. I found out I have asked 10 questions already, and provided 0 answers. Is it okay for me to keep asking questions, while making minimal contributions to the answers here?

Comment: You have used your free trial of TeX.SE!! Now you have to pay!! :) Of course that's perfectly fine. We are here to exchange knowledge and not keep up with user stats. Just be a good sport and that's all you need. If you like an answer vote & accept, that would create a mild satisfaction and a sense of usefulness for the answerers.

Comment: Good questions (typically with a MWE that demonstrates the problem) are always welcome. It doesn't matter if you don't answer any. There are some of us who have answered but never asked. You can also help the site by voting other questions and answers.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot I think users who never asked questions should finally ask one :)

Comment: @Skillmon Some of the users here worked on the LaTeX kernel. It's hard to imagine what kind of question they'd have that the rest of us could answer. :-)

Comment: @NicolaTalbot David could for example ask, what I had for lunch today. I assure you no one of the kernel team can answer this :)

Comment: @Skillmon This is true, although I have a sneaky suspicion that it might be closed as off-topic. :-)

Comment: @NicolaTalbot: There are lots of question that David could ask: What is documentation for?, How is reading documentation not cheating? How to write xii.tex to make it _more_ readable? How to translate picture mode to tikz, etc... :-) :-)

Comment: One thing you could do is to try to make the questions as generic as possible and not too specific to your current problem. That way it could help out other people in the future. I try to do that (but don't always succeed) and often end up getting the "Why the heck do you want to do that" (so now I try to include that info as well). so, go ahead and ask...

Comment: Out of curiosity, do people get given grief if they ask more questions than they answer on Maths SE?

Comment: @cfr I have no answer. All I know is that many of the top users ask no questions at all.

Comment: @Skillmon I'm sure you ate Duck.

Comment: @PeterGrill I could ask what colour are trees in California

Comment: @DavidCarlisle yesterday I did, but today I only ate salad for lunch (which sadly didn't contain any duck meat).

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: They are all black now with the fires. :-)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Is it okay for me to keep asking questions, while making minimal contributions to the answers here?

Absolutely!

A high quality contribution is a high quality contribution.

Other people may have the same problem that you are having and if you've already asked a good question they can find the answer and that's great. You can also get the information you need to enjoy your (La)TeX-ing. And maybe with time you'll learn more and get better and be able to help others, but it doesn't matter if not.

There are some users here who are the complete opposite.

Our top five users have just 108 questions between them, but 41,666 answers and 2,188,246 rep points.

The top two have no questions between them, but 25,526 answers and 1,131,507 rep points.

Comment: Did you you mean to say that "A high quality question is a high quality contribution"?

Comment: @Circumscribe it means: Making good questions contribute to the site...

Comment: @Circumscribe I didn't actually =) What I meant was a high quality contribution, whatever form it may take, whether it's a question or an answer, is still a high quality contribution. And therefore valuable. Doesn't matter whether you're asking questions or answering them, it still counts :)

Comment: Fair enough, that's valid (and also true).

Comment: Maybe if TeX.SX had been active 30 years ago, I could have made some questions. 